# Yii CGridView assign class on data value

Tags: php, yii

I am bigner to Yii and trying to make one application.

in my view i am using

```
zii.widgets.grid.CGridView
```

i have one colum displaing results as bellow

```
array(
 'name'  => 'name',
  'value' => 'CHtml::link("<span class=\"label label-success\">".$data->getStatus()."</span> ".$data->name."<br> View Status <br> Copy Draft)',
'type'  => 'raw',
 ),
```

Here i have `<span class=` , i want to change `class` of `SPAN` depend upon the data of `$data->getStatus()`, like if `Status is Draft`, i want to assign class as `Label Warning` and when `Status is Sent` i want to assign class `label label-success`

how can i do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a funtion in your CActiveRecord

```
class YourClasseModel extends CActiveRecord 
{



    public function renderYourValue($data,$row)
    {

        if ($data->getStatus == 'Sent')  {
            return CHtml::link("<span class=\"label label-success\">".$data->getStatus()."</span> ".$data->name."<br> View Status <br> Copy Draft");
        }
        if ($data->getStatus == 'Draft')
    }
.......


 'value'=>array($model,'renderYourValue'),
```

and the call the function in your column

```
array(
    'name'  => 'name',
    'value' =>     'value'=>array($model,'renderYourValue'), 
    'type'  => 'raw',
 ),
```